# Understanding the right assumption about Gateaux derivative in Banach spaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, gateaux-derivative

It is a general fact that the notion of [Gateaux derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative) is not **uniform** over the mathematical community i.e. someone requires it to be linear and continue other not and require this additional property explicitly if they have to use it. Now I'm referring to the book **Drabek, Milnor - Methods of Nonlinear Analysis**

[image: definitions of Gateaux Derivative according to Drabek, Milnor]

as you can see in the example 3.2.3 (I don't post the second page because it's obvious) Drabek, Milota build the Jacobi Matrix of the Gateaux Derivative of a **general function f**. BUT not every function has a linear Gateaux derivative (a matrix is the representation of a linear - and in this case continuous- function right?)! (think of $x \to |x|$ for example). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The authors are proving that, if $f$ is G-differentiable at $a$, then the G-derivative is the Jacobi matrix. Of course the Jacobi matrix can be written also for functions that are not G-differentiable (since we simply need the existence of the partial derivatives).

Comment: mmh how can you write the jacobi matrix for non G-differentiable functions? am I forcing them to be linear and continuous?

Comment: Read the definition of the Jacobi matrix. Do you see any reference to G-derivatives? I can see only partial derivatives.

Comment: ok, but my doubt is (maybe it's a silly question). Start with a generic function, suppose the existence of partial derivatives (which are, according to me g-derivative, taking the direction of elements of the standard basis) Then I can build a matrix which represent the G-differential over this basis. In fact the existence of the partial derivative implies the G-differential to be linear and continuous. If I remember, a sufficient condition would be the continuity of the partial derivative. but here I don't see any hypothesis over them

Comment: The continuity of the partial derivatives implies the Fréchet-differentiabilty, a stronger kind of differentiability.

Comment: mmh ok, i think I've solve my doubt :) just a messed up definition. Thanks again!